# UWP - Changing Alpha on specific pixel in uwp

Tags: android, image, multidimensional-array, uwp, pixel

im struggeling for a long while now. Im trying to change the alpha channel on a specific pixel of a image. I want to convert an image to a 2D array with only alpha channels. I got this working in Android, but don't know how in UWP.

**Android version**

```
short[][] dotMapArray;
short[][] heatMapArray;
int[] scolorGradiant;

void init() {
    Bitmap dotBitmap = loadImageFromResources(DOT);
    Bitmap gradiantBitmap = loadImageFromResources(SPECTRUMPIC);

    // initializing the 'dot' for the points on the heatmap
    dotMapArray = new short[dotBitmap.getWidth()][dotBitmap.getHeight()];
    print(true, "Converting Dot image to black image");
    for (int x = 0; x < dotBitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < dotBitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
            dotMapArray[x][y] = (short) (Color.alpha(dotBitmap.getPixel(x, y)));
            if (dotMapArray[x][y] > 255)
                dotMapArray[x][y] = 255;
        }
    }
    // initializing the color gradiant
    scolorGradiant = new int[gradiantBitmap.getHeight()];
    int gradiant, pixelColor;
    for (int y = 0; y < scolorGradiant.length; y++) {
        gradiant = gradiantBitmap.getPixel(0, y); // color
        pixelColor = Color.argb(90, Color.red(gradiant), Color.green(gradiant), Color.blue(gradiant));
        scolorGradiant[y] = pixelColor;
    }

}
```

How do I do this in UWP?
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a loop that checks 1st channel (BGRA) if blue = 255 then all channels go to 0

```
        var pixels = yourWriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.Length; i += 4)
        {
            if (pixels[i] == 255)
            {
                pixels[i] = 0;
                pixels[i + 1] = 0;
                pixels[i + 2] = 0;
                pixels[i + 3] = 0;
            }
        }
        using (var stream = yourWriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
        }
```